# How to rename each dataframe from a list of names

Tags: python

I've searched online a lot but it wasn't useful.
That's where I'm stuck:

```
path = os.getcwd() # define path
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv")) # read all files with suffix csv

list_of_dataframes = [] # create empty array
names = []
for f in csv_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    list_of_dataframes.append(df) # add all dfs in this object
    names.append(f.split("\\")[-1].replace(".csv", "")) # double slash to set where to split data (try without to understand)
    # -1 to get final part of string (they are paths)
    # command strip, lstrip and rstrip is not useful, let's use replace
    print(f.split("\\")[-1].replace(".csv", ""))
```

Here I loaded all the csvs from directory and saved them.
In names I have this:

```
['circuits',
 'constructors',
 'constructor_results',
 'constructor_standings',
 'drivers',
 'driver_standings',
 'lap_times',
 'pit_stops',
 'qualifying',
 'races',
 'results',
 'seasons',
 'sprint_results',
 'status']
```

These are the names I want to call each corresponding dataframe.
list_of_dataframes is another list with all dataframes appended.

What I want to achieve is:

```
circuits = list_of_dataframes[0]
constructors = list_of_dataframes[1]
...
```

So I want to be able to call each dataframes by its csv name.
I've tried that but it's not working as I would:

```
for i in range(len(list_of_dataframes)):
    names[i] = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dataframes[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, your problem statement is quite confuse for me.

If I understand correctly, you have a Dataframe `df` that is linked to the `filename` where its data came from. I would use a `dict` in this case since you already have the `name<->value`. Thus:

```
dfs={}
for filename in ....:
    dfs[filename]=pd.read_csv(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
path = os.getcwd() # define path
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv")) # read all files with suffix csv

df = {}
for f in csv_files:
    fileName = f.split("\\")[-1].replace(".csv", "")
    df[fileName] = pd.read_csv(f)
```

you can create dictionary of dataframe and accessed all your data frame by `df['circuits']` etc..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `locals()` function.

Suppose we create a list of file names as below:

```
names = ['data0', 'data1', 'data2']
```

We want to load in a bunch of .csv files with long names and just use our names from the names list.

```
# start with a counter
i = 0

for file in files:
    # make an empty data frame
    df = pd.DataFrame()

    df = pd.read_csv(file, low_memory=False)

    # get the name from the list
    new_name = names[I]

    # now assign it using the locals() command
    locals()[new_name] = df.copy()

    # increment to get the next one
    i = i + 1
```

Now there with be three new dataframes called data0, data1, data2